# VBA SaveAs xlsm specific name with location prompt

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a new workbook, then save it in xlsm format **in a prompted location** with the file name:

```
"Combined ALC Depot Reports " & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY")
```

The code I have is below.  Currently it prompts you for the location, but it doesn't fill in the file name.

```
Sub NewWb()
Dim Aname As String
Dim fileToSaveAs As Variant

Aname = "Combined ALC Depot Reports " & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY")
Workbooks.Add

ChDir "C:/temp/" 'Change to initial path

fileToSaveAs = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Aname, FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

 If fileToSaveAs <> False Then
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fileToSaveAs, FileFormat:=52
 End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the `chdir` and include the path into Aname. the below code worked perfectly, opening in TEMP folder with a default name TEST:

```
Sub NewWb()
    Dim Aname As String
    Dim fileToSaveAs As Variant

    Aname = "c:\temp\test"
    Workbooks.Add

    ChDir "C:\" '--->no effect

    fileToSaveAs = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Aname, FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

     If fileToSaveAs <> False Then
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileToSaveAs, FileFormat:=52
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I replace "test" with "Combined ALC Depot Reports " it does almost what I want, but as soon as I change Aname to the below, it doesn't provide a default name. Thoughts?
:      Aname = "c:\temp\Combined ALC Depot Reports" & Format(Date, "MM.DD.YY")

Comment: Just realized that if I do Format(Date, "MM-DD-YY") it works, so I'm going with that.  Thank you for your help!